# Moq - Setup .Equals method to return false

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I can't figure out how to make Moq setup the .Equals method on objects. The following assertion fails:

```
var Song = new Mock<ISong>();
Song.Setup(x => x.Equals(Song.Object))
    .Returns(false);

Assert.IsFalse(Song.Object.Equals(Song.Object));
```

In other words, `Song.Object.Equals(Song.Object)` always returns true.

Is it at all possible to mock the `.Equals` method with `Moq`? What am I missing?

Comment: You are doing a Setup for Song.Equals, not Song.Object.Equals. If you test Song.Equals(Song.Object), it should return false...

Comment: Well, wait what? I've written all my tests using the Mock.Object as actual mock. And it worked for all other 30+ tests. Why would it fail for this one? EDIT: that's indeed what they show on their first tutorial entry: https://github.com/moq/moq4

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I did the same as you and got the same result. If I add an "bool Equals(object obj)" to my ISong interface, then it works... which makes sense to me... I can elaborate in an answer if you want me to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of Castle.Core (used internally by Moq and other mocking frameworks like NSubstitute). It can't override virtual methods defined on `System.Object`, i.e., `ToString`, `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

The workaround is to manually override these methods somewhere in the inheritance tree.

For example, this will fail:

```
public class Class {}

var m = Mock.Of<Class>(c =>
    c.Equals(It.IsAny<object>()) == true
    );

Assert.True(m.Equals(null));
```

But this will pass:

```
public class Class
{
    public override bool Equals(object o) => base.Equals(o);
}

var m = Mock.Of<Class>(c =>
    c.Equals(It.IsAny<object>()) == true
    );

Assert.True(m.Equals(null));
```

Since you're using an interface, you can simply declare the method on it: `bool Equals(object o);`

Comment: That fixed it. Brilliant :)